# GDI+ Bitmap Disposal and Invalid Parameter Errors

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+

I'm writing an application to draw some images for me using some intermediary bitmaps, but I'm getting an invalid parameter error from GDI+ (the graphics class) if I dispose of the intermediary bitmap being used to resize the image before the bitmap is drawn.

The application itself is designed to take input images and output them cropped and resized to an image file. Now this means that at one point in time the resized image is stored in an intermediary bitmap. When the resizing is done the intermediary bitmap is assigned to the original bitmap which is then drawn with GDI+ and the intermediary is disposed of. However for some reason if the intermediary is disposed of before the original image gets redrawn (despite its values being assigned to another variable and is theoretically unneeded) the program throws an invalid parameter error and i was curious why.

This version throws the invalid parameter error

```
using system.drawing;
Bitmap Background = new Bitmap(*filepath*);
Bitmap Image = new Bitmap(*another filepath*);
Bitmap ResizedImage = new Bitmap(825, 1125);
...Some code that clips and resizes Image and draws it onto ResizedImage...
Image = ResizedImage;
ResizedImage.Dispose();
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Background)
{
  g.DrawImage(Image, 0, 0, 825, 1125);
}
```

But this version doesn't and only the position of one line changes

```
using system.drawing;
Bitmap Background = new Bitmap(*filepath*);
Bitmap Image = new Bitmap(*another filepath*);
Bitmap ResizedImage = new Bitmap(825, 1125);
...Some code that clips and resizes Image and draws it onto ResizedImage...
Image = ResizedImage;
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Background)
{
  g.DrawImage(Image, 0, 0, 825, 1125);
  ResizedImage.Dispose();
}
```

Since ResizedImage has its contents copied into Image before it is disposed of, Image should draw just fine, but I get an invalid parameter error if I use the first bit of code and I just wanted to know why. I'm guessing it has something to do with how the bitmap assignments *actually* work than i'm not aware of but some more sage advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem

```
Image = ResizedImage;
```

`Bitmap` is a *reference type*, at this point `Image` and `ResizedImage` are both pointing to the same bit of memory. The original `Image` gets lost and becomes a memory leak

Then you call `Dispose()` on `ResizedImage` which is the same *reference* as `Image` now (`ResizedImage == Image`)

```
ResizedImage.Dispose();
```

Then try and use it again (remembering `Image` is a disposed `ResizedImage`)

```
g.DrawImage(Image, 0, 0, 825, 1125);
```

In short, don't do this `Image = ResizedImage;`, also use `using` statements

Comment: Ah ok so it does have to do with the way the assignment works. Guess I better look into how I can plug that memory leak up but keeping the functionality. (the code is wrapped in some using statements but I might need to add some more )

Comment: So would using something like the .clone method work to plug the memory leak? ie do all the cropping and resizing on the same bitmap object instead of making another eg: Image = Image.Clone(cropped rectangle, etc)

Comment: @NeoEyes as far as I can tell you just need to use ResisedImage for your drawimage. That way you can dispose Image naturally